# How to add an element between 2 flex-styled rows and make the row below move down based on new element height?

Tags: javascript, css, grid, flexbox

Please take a look at this basic example:

http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ResponsiveFullWidthGrid/

Now imagine that by clicking a cat box, I would need (especially on small to medium screens) to add a 100%-width text box (say a description of the clicked cat) below the clicked cat's row. That text box should push down the rest of the rows.

I am full css/js/frontend developer but I never faced a problem like this. It's also the first time I'm going to use a flexbox layout. With a fixed layout would be quite trivial, but in this case I cannot figure out a good way of doing it. One of the things to solve for example is: where should I put the box (relative to the clicked box?), and should I change position via javascript based on current items-per-row or maybe there a smarter css way?

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

That was an interesting challenge :)

The only way to know where to place the expanded area (I called it infoBox), is to identify the 1st node of the next line, and then insert it before it. If there is no node on the last line, we can append it to the end of the `ul`.

I've also added a window.resize event handler that will close the infoBox, so it won't break the responsive layout, and a close button.

Working example - [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/OriDrori/f1LkgLs6/7/).

HTML was copy paste from the [codrop](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/responsive-full-width-grid/) article.

JS

```
var rfgrid = document.querySelector('.cbp-rfgrid');
var items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.cbp-rfgrid > li'));

/** Create infoBox **/
var infoBox = document.createElement('div');
infoBox.classList.add('infoBox');
infoBox.innerHTML = '<div class="close">X</div><div class="content"></div>';
infoBoxClose = infoBox.querySelector('.close');
infoBoxContent = infoBox.querySelector('.content');

/** add close button functionality **/
infoBoxClose.addEventListener('click', function() {
    rfgrid.removeChild(infoBox);
});

/** remove infoBox on resize to maintain layout flow **/
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    rfgrid.removeChild(infoBox);
});

items.forEach(function (item) {
    item.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var insertReference = findReference(this); // get refence to next line 1st node
        infoBoxContent.innerHTML = items.indexOf(this); // example of changing infoBox content

        if(insertReference) {
            rfgrid.insertBefore(infoBox, insertReference); // insert infoBox before the reference
        } else {
            rfgrid.appendChild(infoBox); // insert infoBox as last child
        };
    });
});

/** find reference to 1st item of next line or null if last line **/
function findReference(currentNode) {
    var originalTop = currentNode.offsetTop; // get the clicked item offsetTop

    do {
        currentNode = currentNode.nextSibling; // get next sibling
    } while (currentNode !== null && (currentNode.nodeType !== 1 || currentNode.offsetTop === originalTop)); // keep iterating until null (last line) or a node with a different offsetTop (next line)

    return currentNode;
}
```

CSS (in addition to the original)

```
.infoBox {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    clear: both;
    background: paleturquoise;
}

.infoBox > .close {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    right: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```